# Can gcc/g++ tell me when it ignores my register?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, cpu-registers

When compiling C/C++ codes using gcc/g++, if it ignores my register, can it tell me?
For example, in this code

```
int main()
{
    register int j;
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
        for(j = 0; j < 32000; j++)
            ;
    return 0;
}
```

j will be used as register, but in this code

```
int main()
{
    register int j;
    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
        for(j = 0; j < 32000; j++)
            ;
    int * a = &j;
    return 0;
}
```

j will be a normal variable.
Can it tell me whether a variable I used register is really stored in a CPU register?

Comment: You could look at the generated assembly, if you really wanted to... but is there really a reason you need to know?

Comment: You should not be taking the address of a variable qualified as `register` — to my knowledge this is expressly forbidden in C89/C99.

Comment: @detly It's valid in C++ but not C

Comment: @detly: From MSDN, "ANSI C does not allow for taking the address of a register object; this restriction does not apply to C++. However, if the address-of operator (&) is used on an object, the compiler must put the object in a location for which an address can be represented. In practice, this means in memory instead of in a register." Since the poster is coding in "C/C++", one rule or the other may apply.

Comment: @det: Recent GCC won't complain about referencing a register: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00109.html

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, @Daniel Daranas, @Potatoswatter — I suspected it might be okay in C++, but I don't have a lot of experience on that side. I think I interpreted the **C** /C++ too literally...

Comment: It is indeed OK in C++. All the standard has to say is "A `register` specifier has the same semantics as an `auto` specifier together with a hint to the compiler that the object so declared will be heavily used. [Note: the hint can be ignored and in most implementations it will be ignored if the address of the object is taken.]"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fairly assume that GCC ignores the `register` keyword except perhaps at `-O0`.  However, it shouldn't make a difference one way or another, and if you are in such depth, you should already be reading the assembly code.

Here is an informative thread on this topic: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-05/msg00098.html . Back in the old days, `register` indeed helped compilers to allocate a variable into registers, but today register allocation can be accomplished optimally, automatically, without hints. The keyword does continue to serve two purposes in C:

1. In C, it prevents you from taking the address of a variable. Since registers don't have addresses, this restriction can help a simple C compiler. (Simple C++ compilers don't exist.)
2. A `register` object cannot be declared `restrict`. Because `restrict` pertains to addresses, their intersection is pointless. (C++ does not yet have `restrict`, and anyway, this rule is a bit trivial.)

For C++, the keyword has been deprecated since C++11 and [proposed for removal](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4340.html) from the standard revision scheduled for 2017.

Some compilers have used `register` on parameter declarations to determine the calling convention of functions, with the ABI allowing mixed stack- and register-based parameters. This seems to be nonconforming, it tends to occur with extended syntax like `register("A1")`, and I don't know whether any such compiler is still in use.

Comment: No, see e.g Nick T's answer why a compiler can't ignore a `register` keyword, at least in C this constrains the use of the variable. One just should take the term "register" verbally, this is interdiction of taking addresses is the only purpose of this keyword. Unfortunately it is a misnomer.

Comment: @Jens: I answered in the context of the question. Note the word "assume": if the compiler rejects the code, assumptions are moot.

Comment: @JensGustedt rather than calling the keyword a 'misnomer', I'd say you are incorrectly labelling a side-effect of an obsolete keyword as its 'purpose'. I don't see why removing this side effect (i.e., completely ignoring the keyword, rather than ignoring it but enforcing the side-effect) is a problem. The prohibition was useful in K&R C because it allowed the compiler to assign registers to variables without knowing if any `&` were being done later. C Compilers were very, um, 'linear' back then.

Comment: @greggo, in C, `register` is not obsolete and this is not a side-effect. The fact that in C you don't have the right to take the address of a `register` is the difference to specifying with `auto`. Objects that aren't addressable also occur at another point in the C standard, namely they behave differently on initialization. And that section also makes explicit reference to `register`.

Comment: @JensGustedt That is the difference which remains. But what is the reason it's there in the first place? 'register' was originally there to hint the compiler. What the justification is for forbidding &? Originally it was simply because K&R C compiler would allocate locals to register or stack frame, as soon as it saw the declaration, and then proceed to compile code following. You can't do that unless you forbid & of a register variable, as I already alluded. Since the only way it could support & of a local is to put in the stack, it was easier just to forbid 'register'  in the first place...

Comment: @JensGustedt but if 'register' has new use case that I'm not aware of, I apologize .. I just can't see a reason a programmer would want to tag certain locals to forbid taking their address, and even if so, using 'register' is a rather confusing way to do it, given the historical context.

Comment: @greggo, that is not new, it is there as it is now since the standardization of C. It hasn't changed since then. And I agree that this is confusing, so I call it a misnomer. "Addressfree" or something like that would be a better term.  The reasons to use that are, as from the beginning, potential optimization. In particular variables that are `register` and `const` are interesting for that since they can't alias. `register` allows the compiler to warn me about a missed optimization.

Comment: @JensGustedt well the orginal *purpose* was to tell the old compiler - which did *not* look at the code before deciding register allocation - to put that variable in a register if possible. That *purpose* is indeed obsolete, but the restriction supporting it remains. 'Addressfree' property is indeed very important, but it's now determined easily & reliably by looking at how you actually use the variable (same is true for 'const', in regard to optimizing). I don't see how a 'register' keyword can allow the compiler to warn you about a missed optimization.

Comment: @greggo, if I declare a variable `register` it can never alias, and I can't change that property by taken its address by mistake.

Comment: @Potatoswatter "2 It can affect the calling convention of a function" - if so it seems to me there would be a requirement that a function defined as `int foo(register int a) {...}` would need to be prototyped with the `register int a`, I've never heard of such a requirement. It may be that there are some compilers that implement this as an extension, but generally `__attribute__` is used for specifying different ABIs. Even in the 'olden days', "register" on a parm meant "passed on stack as usual, pls copy to a register"

Comment: @greggo Good point. The implementations I'm thinking of also introduced nonconforming syntax with `register` parameters See http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/embedded/2015-February/000396.html . However, a conforming way around the issue would be to pass by register if any declaration includes `register`.

Comment: … And, forbid the user from adding a declaration with `register` where none existed before. Perhaps that's not conforming after all. I'll remove that from the answer.

Answer (score 7):

With respect to modern compilation and optimization techniques, the `register` annotation does not make any sense at all. In your second program you take the address of `j`, and registers do not have addresses, but one same local or static variable could perfectly well be stored in two different memory locations during its lifetime, or sometimes in memory and sometimes in a register, or not exist at all. Indeed, an optimizing compiler would compile your nested loops as nothing, because they do not have any effects, and simply assign their final values to `k` and `j`. And then omit these assignments because the remaining code does not use these values.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the address of a register in C, plus the compiler can totally ignore you; C99 standard, section 6.7.1 [(pdf)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> The implementation may treat any
>   register declaration simply as an auto
>   declaration. However, whether or not
>   addressable storage is actually used,
>   the address of any part of an object
>   declared with storage-class specifier
>   register cannot be computed, either
>   explicitly (by use of the unary &
>   operator as discussed in 6.5.3.2) or
>   implicitly (by converting an array
>   name to a pointer as discussed in
>   6.3.2.1). Thus, the only operator that can be applied to an array declared
>   with storage-class specifier register
>   is sizeof.

Unless you're mucking around on 8-bit AVRs or PICs, the compiler will probably laugh at you thinking you know best and ignore your pleas.  Even on them, I've thought I knew better a couple times and found ways to trick the compiler (with some inline asm), but my code exploded because it had to massage a bunch of other data to work around my stubbornness.

Comment: AVR is interesting to mention in this context, since AVR general registers are mapped into DM space and therefore have addresses... (I am aware though, that in the context of C, this isn't helpful unless the variable's residence in the actual register can be guaranteed at all possible derefs of the pointer..)

Answer (score 1):

This question, and some of the answers, and several other discussions of the 'register' keywords I've seen -- seem to assume implicitly that all locals are mapped either to a specific register, or to a specific memory location on the stack. This was generally true until 15-25 years ago, and it's true if you turn off optimizing, but it's not true at all
when standard optimizing is performed. Locals are now seen by optimizers as symbolic names that you use to describe the flow of data, rather than as values that need to be stored in specific locations.

Note: by 'locals' here I mean: scalar variables, of storage class auto (or 'register'), which are never used as the operand of '&'. Compilers can sometimes break up auto structs, unions or arrays into individual 'local' variables, too.

To illustrate this: suppose I write this at the top of a function:

```
int factor = 8;
```

.. and then the only use of the `factor` variable is to multiply by various things:

```
arr[i + factor*j] = arr[i - factor*k];
```

In this case - try it if you want - there will be no `factor` variable. The code analysis will show that `factor` is always 8, and so all the shifts will turn into `<<3`. If you did the same thing in 1985 C, `factor` would get a location on the stack, and there would be multipilies, since the compilers basically worked one statement at a time and didn't remember anything about the values of the variables. Back then programmers would be more likely to use `#define factor 8` to get better code in this situation, while maintaining adjustable `factor`.

If you use `-O0` (optimization off) - you will indeed get a variable for `factor`. This will allow you, for instance, to step over the `factor=8` statement, and then change `factor` to 11 with the debugger, and keep going. In order for this to work, the compiler can't keep *anything* in registers between statements, except for variables which are assigned to specific registers; and in that case the debugger is informed of this. And it can't try to 'know' anything about the values of variables, since the debugger could change them. In other words, you need the 1985 situation if you want to change local variables while debugging.

Modern compilers generally compile a function as follows:

(1) when a local variable is assigned to more than once in a function, the compiler creates different 'versions' of the variable so that each one is only assigned in one place. All of the 'reads' of the variable refer to a specific version.

(2) Each of these locals is assigned to a 'virtual' register. Intermediate calculation results are also assigned variables/registers; so

```
  a = b*c + 2*k;
```

becomes something like

```
       t1 = b*c;
       t2 = 2;
       t3 = k*t2;
       a = t1 + t3;
```

(3) The compiler then takes all these operations, and looks for common subexpressions, etc. Since each of the new registers is only ever written once, it is rather easier to rearrange them while maintaining correctness. I won't even start on loop analysis.

(4) The compiler then tries to map all these virtual registers into actual registers in order to generate code. Since each virtual register has a limited lifetime it is possible to reuse actual registers heavily - 't1' in the above is only needed until the add which generates 'a', so it could be held in the same register as 'a'. When there are not enough registers, some of the virtual registers can be allocated to memory -- or -- a value can be held in a certain register, stored to memory for a while, and loaded back into a (possibly) different register later. On a load-store machine, where only values in registers can be used in computations, this second strategy accomodates that nicely.

From the above, this should be clear: it's easy to determine that the virtual register mapped to `factor` is the same as the constant '8', and so all multiplications by `factor` are multiplications by 8. Even if `factor` is modified later, that's a 'new' variable and it doesn't affect prior uses of `factor`.

Another implication, if you write

```
 vara = varb;
```

.. it may or may not be the case that there is a corresponding copy in the code. For instance

```
int *resultp= ...
int acc = arr[0] + arr[1];
int acc0 = acc;    // save this for later
int more = func(resultp,3)+ func(resultp,-3);
acc += more;         // add some more stuff
if( ...){
    resultp = getptr();
    resultp[0] = acc0;
    resultp[1] = acc;
}
```

In the above the two 'versions' of acc (initial, and after adding 'more') could be in two different registers, and 'acc0' would then be the same as the inital 'acc'. So no register copy would be needed for 'acc0 =acc'.
Another point: the 'resultp' is assigned to twice, and since the second assignment ignores the previous value, there are essentially two distinct 'resultp' variables in the code, and this is easily determined by analysis.

An implication of all this: don't be hesitant to break out complex expressions into smaller ones using additional locals for intermediates, if it makes the code easier to follow. There is basically zero run-time penalty for this, since the optimizer sees the same thing anyway.

If you're interested in learning more you could start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

The point of this answer is to (a) give some idea of how modern compilers work and (b) point out that asking the compiler, if it would be so kind, to put a particular local variable into a register -- doesn't really make sense. Each 'variable' may be seen by the optimizer as several variables, some of which may be heavily used in loops, and others not. Some variables will vanish -- e.g. by being constant; or,  sometimes, the temp variable used in a swap. Or calculations not actually used. The compiler is equipped to use the same register for different things in different parts of the code, according to what's actually best on the machine you are compiling for.

The notion of hinting the compiler as to which variables should be in registers assumes that each local variable maps to a register or to a memory location. This was true back when Kernighan + Ritchie designed the C language, but is not true any more.

Regarding the restriction that you can't take the address of a register variable: Clearly, there's no way to implement taking the address of a variable held in a register, but you might ask - since the compiler has discretion to ignore the 'register' - why is this rule in place? Why can't the compiler just ignore the 'register' if I happen to take the address? (as is the case in C++).

Again, you have to go back to the old compiler. The original K+R compiler would parse a local variable declaration, and then *immediately* decide whether to assign it to a register or not (and if so, which register). Then it would proceed to compile expressions, emitting the assembler for each statement one at a time. If it later found that you were taking the address of a 'register' variable, which had been assigned to a register, there was no way to handle that, since the assignment was, in general, irreversible by then. It was possible, however, to generate an error message and stop compiling.

Bottom line, it appears that 'register' is essentially obsolete:

- C++ compilers ignore it completely
- C compilers ignore it except to enforce the restriction about `&` - and possibly don't ignore it at `-O0` where it could actually result in allocation as requested. At -O0 you aren't concerned about code speed though.

So, it's basically there now for backward compatibility, and probably on the basis that some implementations could still be using it for 'hints'. I never use it -- and I write real-time DSP code, and spend a fair bit of time looking at generated code and finding ways to make it faster. There are many ways to modify code to make it run faster, and knowing how compilers work is very helpful. It's been a long time indeed since I last found that adding 'register' to be among those ways.

---

### Addendum

I excluded above, from my special definition of 'locals', variables to which `&` is applied (these are are of course included in the usual sense of the term).

Consider the code below:

```
void
somefunc()
{
    int h,w;
    int i,j;
    extern int pitch;

    get_hw( &h,&w );  // get shape of array

    for( int i = 0; i < h; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < w; j++ ){
            Arr[i*pitch + j] = generate_func(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

This may look perfectly harmless. But if you are concerned about execution speed, consider this: The compiler is passing the addresses of `h` and `w` to `get_hw`, and then later calling `generate_func`. Let's assume the compiler knows nothing about what's in those functions (which is the general case). The compiler *must* assume that the call to `generate_func` could be changing `h` or `w`. That's a perfectly legal use of the pointer passed to `get_hw` - you could store it somewhere and then use it later, as long as the scope containing `h,w` is still in play, to read or write those variables.

Thus the compiler must store `h` and `w` in memory on the stack, and can't determine anything in advance about how long the loop will run. So certain optimizations will be impossible, and the loop could be less efficient as a result (in this example, there's a function call in the inner loop anyway, so it may not make much of a difference, but consider the case where there's a function which is *occasionally* called in the inner loop, depending on some condition).

Another issue here is that `generate_func` could change `pitch`, and so `i*pitch` needs to done each time, rather than only when `i` changes.

It can be recoded as:

```
void
somefunc()
{
    int h0,w0;
    int h,w;
    int i,j;
    extern int pitch;
    int apit = pitch;

    get_hw( &h0,&w0 );  // get shape of array
    h= h0;
    w= w0;

    for( int i = 0; i < h; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < w; j++ ){
            Arr[i*apit + j] = generate_func(i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the variables `apit,h,w` are all 'safe' locals in the sense I defined above, and the compiler can be sure they won't be changed by any function calls. Assuming I'm *not* modifying anything in `generate_func`, the code will have the same effect as before but could be more efficient.

Jens Gustedt has suggested the use of the 'register' keyword as a way of tagging key variables to inhibit the use of `&` on them, e.g. by others maintaining the code (It won't affect the generated code, since the compiler can determine the lack of `&` without it). For my part, I always think carefully before applying `&` to any local scalar in a time-critical area of the code, and in my view using 'register' to enforce this is a little cryptic, but I can see the point (unfortunately it doesn't work in C++ since the compiler will just ignore the 'register').

Incidentally, in terms of code efficiency, the best way to have a function return two values is with a struct:

```
struct hw {  // this is what get_hw returns
   int h,w;
};

void
somefunc()
{
    int h,w;
    int i,j;

    struct hw hwval = get_hw();  // get shape of array
    h = hwval.h;
    w = hwval.w;
    ...
```

This may look cumbersome (and is cumbersome to write), but it will generate cleaner code than the previous examples. The 'struct hw' will actually be returned in two registers (on most modern ABIs anyway). And due to the way the 'hwval' struct is used, the optimizer will effectively break it up into two 'locals' `hwval.h` and `hwval.w`, and then determine that these are equivalent to `h` and `w` -- so `hwval` will essentially disappear in the code. No pointers need to be passed, no function is modifying another function's variables via pointer; it's just like having two distinct scalar return values. This is much easier to do now in C++11 - with  `std::tie` and `std::tuple`, you can use this method with less verbosity (and without having to write a struct definition).

Comment: That's deff an expert answer! Especially the addendum, gives insight.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is invalid in C. So you see well that the `register` keyword changes something (in C). It is just there for this purpose, to inhibit the taking of an address of a variable. So just don't take its name "register" verbally, it is a misnomer, but stick to its definition.

That C++ seems to ignore `register`, well they must have their reason for that, but I find it kind of sad to again find one of these subtle difference where valid code for one is invalid for the other.

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to say that's it's "purpose". Its original purpose was to allow the programmer to hint the compiler; the restriction was a side-effect of that,  and both made sense in the 80's. But the purpose is now obsolete, and I can't imagine deliberately using `register` to prevent `&` being used. If there is a reason to not use `&`, then by all means write a comment and explain it, otherwise someone will just remove the `register` and do it anyhow... Regarding C++, the 'register' keyword in C++ was included to be compatible with C, and didn't need to carry the restriction with it.